# SwiftUI: Reset TextField value from CoreData on change in value of another state variable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I have a ContentView and a NumericView. The selectedIndex is a @State in ContentView. What I want is that if selectedIndex changes, it should reset the answer field in NumericView from CoreData. Below is the code. "av" contains the value of the answer field from CoreData.

```
struct NumericEntry: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var questionAnswerStore: QuestionAnswerStore
    @State var answer: String
    
    
    var questionIndex: Int

    init(questionIndex: Int, av: String) {
        self.questionIndex = questionIndex
        _answer = State(initialValue: av)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Answer", text: $answer)
                .textFieldStyle(CustomTextFieldStyle())
                .onChange(of: answer) { newValue in
                    self.questionAnswerStore.getUserAttemptData(selectedIndex: questionIndex).answer = newValue
                    PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
                }
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .padding()
            
        }
    }
  
    private struct CustomTextFieldStyle : TextFieldStyle {
        public func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
            configuration
                .padding(10)
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .strokeBorder(Color.secondary.opacity(0.5), lineWidth: 1))
            
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {


   @State var selectedIndex: Int = 0
   @ObservedObject private var questionAnswerStore: QuestionAnswerStore = QuestionAnswerStore.sharedInstance
    

   var body: some View {
      NumericEntry(questionIndex: selectedIndex, av: self.questionAnswerStore.getUserAttemptData(selectedIndex: selectedIndex).answer ?? "")

// some code that keeps changing the value of selectedIndex
  }
}
```

I read somewhere that _stateVariable = State(initialValue: "abcd") should set the state of @State stateVariable. In the above code the code

```
_answer = State(initialValue: av)
```

executes fine but when it reaches

```
TextField("Answer", text: $answer)
```

$answer is still "".

I would prefer a solution where I don't even have to send "av" from the parent component, just selectedIndex should check QuestionAnswerStore for the value of "answer". This could be solved using **.onAppear** but in my case, the NumericView appears only once and then its parent just keeps changing selectedIndex value, so onAppear doesn't get called again.

Of course, if that is not possible then what's the way out using "av" as above?

Comment: Yes, the questionIndex gets updated when it is changed in the ContentView. The code to get answer is 
`
self.questionAnswerStore.getUserAttemptData(selectedIndex: selectedIndex).answer 
`
This is giving the correct value of "answer." I checked that while debugging.

Comment: i think you should set `questionIndex` in `NumericEntry ` as a `Binding` property

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, answer can be updated in the TextField, hence the $answer. Other than that nowhere. It is bound to questionIndex inside the store.. something like:
store = [{"answer": "1"}, {"answer": "2"}]

Comment: @JoakimDanielson In the body of ContentView, // some code that keeps changing the value of selectedIndex ... this part allows user to tap a button and increment the selectedIndex/questionIndex. This index represents index in the store array.